# is it possible to connect to every peer in the Bitcoin network?

Tags: network

I was reading somewhere that you can connect your node to every peer in the Bitcoin network. Is that possible? How would it work?

Comment: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8109/how-does-one-attain-1-000-connections-like-blockchain-info