# Warning: Reducing -maxconnections from 1000 to 865, because of system limitations

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, nodes, connection, performance

I want to be the fastest/first one at recognizing/receiving new transactions, so i set i set these in `bitcoin.conf` and running a `bitcoin full node` on dedicated `centos` server.

```
maxconnections=1000
timeout=15000
```

ref : [How does one attain 1,000+ connections like blockchain.info?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8109/how-does-one-attain-1-000-connections-like-blockchain-info)

but when i restarted the `bitcoind` i get

```
Warning: Reducing -maxconnections from 1000 to 865, because of system limitations.
```

why is that ? and **how can i connect to maximum nodes to make sure i am the first one to get new transactions details**.

**bitcoin version**

```
Bitcoin Core RPC client version v0.14.99.0-6adc3a3
```

Answer (score 2):

Connecting to more nodes will not make you learn about transactions faster, after some point.

Your node will just be busy processing messages - including many uninteresting ones - to maintain connections with all peers, making it slower at processing new things.

Connect to a few fast peers with `-addnode`, or even run multiple nodes yourself, and interconnect them to each other. That will be faster than connecting directly to everyone.

The reason for the reduction of max connections is due to the limited number of file descriptors the operating system granted your `bitcoind` process. You can use the `ulimit` shell command to increase the maximum file descriptor.

Comment: where can i find list of fast peers ?

Comment: Look for yourself. Run a node for a while, see which ones have low ping times, ...

Comment: what if i copy all nodes from https://blockchain.info/connected-nodes and do -addnode on my node, to force connect to all nodes ?

Comment: You can't -addnode more than 8 peers.